# Understanding name spaces in POE-Tk

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, poe

I posted  ["How to undersand the POE-Tk use of destroy?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145532/) in an attempt to reduce the bug in my production code to a test case.  But it seems that the solution to the test case is not working in the full program.

The program is 800+ lines long so I am hesitant to post it in full.  I realize that the snippets I provide here may be too short to be of any use, but I hope to get some direction in either where to look for a solution or what additional information I can provide.

Here is the Session::Create section of my POE-Tk app.

```
POE::Session->create(
    inline_states => {
        _start      => \&ui_start,
        get_zone    => \&get_zone,
        ping        => \&ping,
        mk_disable  => \&mk_disable,
        mk_active   => \&mk_active,
        pop_up_add => \&pop_up_add,
        add_button_press => sub {
            my ($kernel, $session, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, SESSION, HEAP];
            print "\nadd button pressed\n\n";
            &validate;
        },
        ih_button_1_press => sub {
            my ($kernel, $session, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, SESSION, HEAP];
            print "\nih_button_1 pressed\n\n";
            if( Tk::Exists($heap->{ih_mw}) ) {
                print "\n\nih_mw exists in ih_button_1_press\n\n";
            } else {
                print "\n\nih_mw does not exist in ih_button_1_press\n\n";
            }
            1;
            $heap->{ih_mw}->destroy if Tk::Exists($heap->{ih_mw});
            &auth;
        },
        pop_up_del => \&pop_up_del,
        auth        => \&auth,
#       validate    => \&validate,
        auth_routine => \&auth_routine,
        raise_widget    => \&raise_widget,
        del_action  => \&del_action,
        over        => sub { exit; }
    }
);
```

`add_button_press` is called here;

```
sub pop_up_add {
    ...
    my $add_but_2 = $add_frm_2->Button( 
        -text => "Add Record",
        -command => $session->postback("add_button_press"),
        -font => "{Arial} 12 {bold}") -> pack(
            -anchor => 'c',
            -pady => 6,
        );
    ...
}
```

validate creates the Toplevel widget $heap->{ih_mw};

```
sub validate {
    ...
    if( ! $valid ) {
        print "\n! valid entered\n\n";
        $heap->{label_text} .= "Add record anyway?";
        my $lt_ref = \$heap->{label_text};
    ...
        my $heap->{ih_mw} = $heap->{add_mw}->Toplevel( -title => "ih_mw");
    ... 
        if( Tk::Exists($heap->{ih_mw}) ) {
            print "\n\nih_mw exists in validate\n\n";
        } else {
            print "\n\nih_mw does not exist in validate\n\n";
        }
    ...
        my $ih_but1 = $heap->{ih_mw}->Button( -text => "Add",
            -font => 'vfont',
            -command => $session->postback("ih_button_1_press"),
            )->pack( -pady => 5 );
    ...
}
```

Pressing $ih_but1 results in this;

`C:\scripts\alias\resource>alias_poe_V-3_0_par.pl`

add button pressed

sub validate called

! valid entered

`ih_mw` exists in validate

`ih_button_1` pressed

`ih_mw` does not exist in `ih_button_1_press`

So the `$heap->{ih_mw}` widget seems to be unkown to the `ih_button_1_press` anonymous subroutine even with the inclusion of "`($kernel, $session, $heap) = @_[KERNEL, SESSION, HEAP];`"

Comment: Please try to see whether both $heap and $heap->{ih_mw) are actually defined(). If $heap isn't defined then you could possibly still have the same problem as in your previous post.

Comment: I added a if(defined($heap)) in front of the if( Tk::Exists($heap->{ih_mw}) ).  It came back that $heap is defined.
ih_button_1 pressed... 



heap is defined...  



ih_mw does not exist in ih_button_1_press...

Comment: What about defined($heap->{ih_mw})?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does $heap in &validate come from? You don't pass it as a parameter. Could $heap in &validate and $heap in &in_button_1_press not be the same thing? Have you tried printing the stringy form of $heap to see if the addresses are the same in the two functions?

Comment: Some missing code;

use Tk;
use POE qw( Loop::TkActiveState );

From perldoc POE::Session;

POE::Session's Calling Convention
  sub handle_event {
    my ($kernel, $heap, $parameter) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0];
    ...;
  }

Or the use of C"$_[KERNEL]", C"$_[HEAP]" and C"$_[ARG0]" inline, as is done in most examples.

What's going on here is rather basic. Perl passes parameters into subroutines or methods using the @_ array. "KERNEL", "HEAP", "ARG0" and others are constants exported by POE::Session (which is included for free when a program uses POE).

"stringy form of $heap"?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: where does $heap come from in &validate? You call &validate from add_button_press without any arguments, so if you're getting $heap in &validate via $heap = @_[HEAP], then you're going to be in for a surprise. Also, the &validate form of function calling, vs just plain validate, does *not* inherit @_ from the calling context.

Comment: Whoops. This doesn't look right (in validate):
   my $heap->{ih_mw} ...

Try that without the 'my', and see if it works better.

Comment: Andrew, if you will post that as an answer, I will be glad to check and upvote it ;).  Many thanks. - Jon

Comment: From perlsub (1): &NAME; # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.

Comment: Doh! I knew it was something like that. Thanks Inshalla.